# Solution verification for question involving finite topological space

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology, solution-verification

I'm studying for comprehensive exams and was working on a question that comes from a past-exam bank that my school provides. Here is the question:

**Problem.** Let $X$ be the topological space whose points are $\{a,b,x,y\}$ and whose topology is
$$\bigl\{ \{a,b,x,y\}, \{a,x,b\}, \{a,y,b\}, \{a,b\}, \{a\}, \{b\}, \{\} \bigr\}.$$

a) Prove that $X$ is path connected.

b) What is $\pi_1(X,a)$?

c) Describe the universal cover $\tilde X$ of $X$ by indicating a basis for the topology of $\tilde X$.

d) Explain why $X$ does not have the same homotopy type as the circle $S^1$. ∎

Here are my answers, some of which I feel might be a bit incomplete and would probably not get full marks on an exam. I would be grateful if someone could look through the answers and let me know what could be filled in to make these proper and rigorous.

*Solution.* For part (a), note that the function $[0,1]\to X$ that maps $[0,1/2)$ to $a$ and
$[1/2, 1]$ to $x$ is continuous creates a path from $a$ to $x$ in $X$. By symmetry, we can replace $a$
by $b$ and $x$ by $y$. To get from $a$ to $b$, we compose a
path from, say, $a$ to $x$ with a path from $x$ to $b$. We get from $x$ to $y$ in similar fashion.

For part (b), let $f: S^1\to X$ such that $f(1) = a$. In order that $f$ not be nullhomotopic, we
need the image of $f$ to have at least three points. But it is impossible to have a
path from $x$ to $y$ without
passing through either $a$ or $b$, and if we go back through $a$
any number of times without ever visiting $b$, then the result is nullhomotopic. Thus
any non-nullhomotopic map from $S^1$ to $X$ passes through all four points. Furthermore, it must do so either
by going $a \to x\to b\to y\to a$ or the other way around, and it can do so any integer number
of times. Thus we see that $\pi_1(X,a) = {\bf Z}$.

For part (c), note that a base of $X$ is given by $\bigl\{\{a\}, \{b\}, \{a,b,y\}, \{a,b,x\}\bigr\}$.
To construct the universal cover of $X$, we take the set of points
$$\bigcup_{n\in {\bf Z}} \{a_n, b_n, x_n, y_n\}$$
and let its topology be generated by the set
$$\bigcup_{n\in {\bf Z}} \bigl\{\{a_n\}, \{b_n\}, \{a_n,b_n,y_n\}, \{a_{n+1},b_n,x_n\}\bigr\}.$$
(We now see that there is no non-nullhomotopic paths from any $a_n$ to itself, but instead we have a path
from $a_n\to x_n \to b_n \to y_n \to a_{n+1}$ for every $n$, so this space is simply connected.)

Part (d) I was completely baffled by, since $\pi_0(X)$ and $\pi_1(X)$ were the same, and I imagined that all higher homotopy groups of $X$ are zero. I mistakenly thought that having all homotopy groups equal is the same as having the same homotopy type. But after some Googling, I found [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4581611/691096) which sort of explains why they do not have the same homotopy type, though I would appreciate any elaboration of what that answer means by "degree theory" or the particular proof that a non-surjective map cannot be homotopic to the identity. ∎

Comment: Since any map $f:X\to S^1$ is non-surjective, its image is missing at least one point in $S^1$, so the map factors through $S^1\setminus\{x_0\}\approx \Bbb R$ which is contractible. This shows that every such map is null-homotopic.

Comment: @Kevin.S Oh, yes that makes sense; I get a bit muddled up in my head between the identity map and the map sending everything to $1$. Thanks!